# How to run a Python script in the background from a Bash script?

Tags: python, bash, nonblocking

So I have a Bash script that does a bunch of things, one of them (actually the first one) is blink an LED on a RPi (via Python).

The problem is that when I run the Python script it blocks all other scripts and nothing else runs.

I think that by adding an `&` it runs in the background but that didn't make any difference when I tried it.

This is what I have:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo python /scripts/blink.py blinkRed &
rm test.txt test.bkp
...
```

So basically everything stops after running the blink.py script.

Any ideas on how I could make it non-blocking, run it on another thread, on the background or something like that?

Comment: By the way, the Python script is an infinite loop `while(1): ...`

Comment: are you running the script as root?

Comment: can you please change the first line to `#!/bin/bash -x` to confirm that everything runs as expected (and post the output)

Comment: @ReutSharabani well kind of, it's being run by www-data actually, but it has root access

Comment: @matt if it's run by `www-data` which has all needed permissions, why are you using `sudo`?

Comment: if you add an echo foo after the python call do you see any output?

Comment: @ReutSharabani yes, true, I don't really need `sudo`

Comment: @matt does it work without sudo?

Comment: _"So basically everything stops after running the blink.py script."_ and _"By the way, the Python script is an infinite loop "_ So, strictly speaking, there is _no_ "after running the script" as the script never terminates. Couldn't you be fooled by some kind or race condition-like -- the "rest" of the script being executed before the background Python process had even time to start ? In addition, how does behave sudo in that case regarding asking the password (maybe it isn't required given your configuration ?)

Comment: @ReutSharabani yeah it runs without `sudo` as well

Comment: @matt I was asking if it's solved. If it is please say so and I'll add an answer.

Comment: @WoJ yup everything run until the end with `#!/bin/bash -x`

Answer (score 2):

If you have all permissions needed, don't use `sudo`. It is probably waiting for a password to change permissions.

Give the user who runs the script all permissions needed and remove the `sudo`.